# Difference between passing event handler prop as arrow function or function reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a class Component, I have something like this:

```js
render() {
  const { onClose } = this.props;

  // later, in the return statement, inside a bunch of other nested markup:
  <CloseIcon onClick={() => onClose()} className="qmCloseButton" />
  <AnotherIcon onClick={() => onClose("/path1")} className="qmCloseButton" />
  <AnotherIcon onClick={() => onClose("/path2")} className="qmCloseButton" />
}
```

The close handler prop that I pass in is:

```js
const onCloseModal = urlAfterClose => {
  if (urlAfterClose) {
    history.push(urlAfterClose);
  } else {
    setShowSuccessModal(false);
  }
};
```

Everything works. However, I always like to avoid arrow functions in my markup when I can, so I try this small change:

```js
  <CloseIcon onClick={onClose} className="qmCloseButton" />
  <AnotherIcon onClick={() => onClose("/path1")} className="qmCloseButton" />
  <AnotherIcon onClick={() => onClose("/path2")} className="qmCloseButton" />
```

But for the `CloseIcon`, the `onClose` method gets called with a class (looks like it might be the component itself?) instead of being called with no argument. It only works as an arrow function.

What am I missing here?

Comment: because it is react's synthetic event. Explained fully in the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

It's totally different syntaxes

`onClick={onClose} =/= () => onClick={()=>onClose()}`

`onClick={onClose}` in JavaScript this will pass all arguments available to onClose function, which second one runs without params

its same as

```
onClick={onClose} = onClick={(e)=>onClose(e)}
```